# C# write out specific cell from CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I am a complete newbie as far as C# goes and I am currently trying to make a program that uses a csv file for source data.

Here's part of my code:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileInput))

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
      if (line.Contains(mK)) // <---Variable inputted by the user
        {
          Console.WriteLine(""+line);
          myValue = File.ReadAllLines(fileInput).Skip(1).First().Split(',')[0];
         }
        LineNumber++;
     }
```

The CSV file I am working with has maybe 8 columns each with a type of information. A single line is like one list of stuff.

However I've been sitting by this for 3 days now and I just have no idea how to have the file print out the specific line and column I want.

The thing I have here goes through each line and when it finds the input somewhere in the line, it writes out the line as a whole.

Afterwards I tried to create a var myValue, which would skip the first (Header) row and write the specific column I entered as the number at the end. However, I somehow need to find a way to change the line. Because it seems to always take the first data line only. I checked if it's reading the line number fine with the int LineNumber++ and it is giving me back the number I want. How do I put that number into the code so that it outputs the specific cell I need?

Comment: Don't put solved in your question title, accepting an answer is how people know it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you reading again the entire file just to skip one single line? You already have the line you are interested into in the `line` variable.

Just split it and get the column you need (the first one I suppose):

```
using(var sr = new StreamReader(fileInput))
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
    if (line.Contains(mK)) // <---Variable inputted by the user
    {
        var value = line.Split(",")[0];
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Federico already answered the question but, here's something for your other question in regards to your `LineNumber` variable.

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileInput))

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        LineNumber++;
        if(LineNumber < 1)//if reading header record
        {
        //skip
        }
        else
        {
        //not reading header line
        //check if the line meets your criteria
          if(line == "my anticipated value")
          {
              line.Split(',')[0];//pull index 0 from the array on strings created by split
          }
        }
     }
```